# Difference between "NOT IN table.col" and "NOT IN SELECT col FROM table"

Tags: sql, oracle

A pretty basic question. But what is the difference between

```
SELECT t.col
FROM table t, other_table o
WHERE t.col NOT IN o.col
```

and

```
SELECT col
FROM table
WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM other_table)
```

Semantically this sounds pretty equal to me, but the first one creates duplicates. What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Does the first query even run?

Comment: It creates duplicates because there is an implicit join happenning between O and T

Comment: The first generates a syntax error.  The second applies a filter to `table.col`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It doesn't create an error for me. This works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one won't even run in most RDBMS, but in oracle it returns every combination of records except  where `t.col` = `o.col`, you'd see this if you added `o.col` to your `SELECT`

The latter query returns records from `table` that don't share the `col` value with any records in `other_table`.

Best illustrated by example:

Table1

```
| ANIMAL |
|--------|
|    dog |
|    cat |
|  horse |
```

Table2

```
| ANIMAL |
|--------|
|    dog |
|   fish |
```

Queries:

```
SELECT t."animal",o."animal"
FROM Table1 t, Table2 o
WHERE t."animal" NOT IN o."animal"

| ANIMAL | ANIMAL2 |
|--------|---------|
|    cat |     dog |
|  horse |     dog |
|    dog |    fish |
|    cat |    fish |
|  horse |    fish |


SELECT t."animal"
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t."animal" NOT IN (SELECT o."animal" FROM Table2 o)

| ANIMAL |
|--------|
|  horse |
|    cat |
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ceecf/3/0)

Basically, you've got a cartesian product in the first query which would return every combination of records from the two tables, but your `WHERE` criteria filters out one of them.  The second query has no `JOIN`, implicit/explicit, it's just taking records from one table and filtering based on criteria that happens to draw from another table.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the query (slightly modified):

```
SELECT t.col
FROM table t, other_table o
WHERE t.col <> o.col
```

makes a cartesian product, then filters it.

The below example might not be the exact process that takes place, but it might give an abstract overview of the situation.

If in table `table` you would have following rows:

```
col
----
A
B
```

and in table `other_table` there would be:

```
col
---
B
E
```

cartesian product (`FROM table t, other_table o`) of the two tables query would probably be:

```
table.col     other_table.col
---------------------------
A             B
A             E
B             B
B             E
```

Then, applying the `WHERE t.col <> o.col` clause the above would be filtered, giving the results

```
table.col     other_table.col
---------------------------
A             B
A             E
B             E
```

Since in the query result set, there is only `table.col` chosen for the output, the final result contains `A` value duplicates:

```
table.col
---------
A        
A        
B
```

I hope it could help you some way.

**# UPDATE**

As for the query:

```
SELECT col
FROM table
WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM other_table)
```

Since there is no join, only the row set from the `table` table is taken into account when building the result.
As far as I understand well, the condition `WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM other_table)` is evaluated against each row from the `table`. 
Column `table.col` is checked whether it belongs to the result set returned by the subquery taking the data from `other_table`. If it validates to TRUE, then, it's taken into result set, if not, it's excluded from it.

Summing it up, I think that the first query doubles the `table.col` values only because of the preparing phase, where the tables are joined (merged) together, thus second query takes to the result set only records from `table` using `other_table` only for validation purposes. That is implicated from the query structure - if I'm right of course.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense however. In my opinion the same should happen for both examples? Whats the difference between `t.col` and `SELECT  col FROM t`?

Comment: @TomTom: The first one is comparing values that occur in the same row of the result set (in this case, `not in` is perfectly equivalent to `<>` because there only ever a single value to the right of the operator) . The second compares a value from each row of the result set to the entire contents of `t`.

Comment: @TomTom: If you like, please find the updated part of the answer - I hope it's not too unclear.

Comment: @T_G Thanks, it's not an easy read but I got I think! I didn't realize that I created a cartesian product with the first query.

Comment: Yes, right :) Sorry for the typos. I've corrected them. Glad could help a little. Regards.